# Getting a tikz picture to have an equation number

Tags: math-mode, tikz-pgf, equations

I make a lot of commutative diagrams and am trying to switch to Tikz from amcd,diagrams, etc. I often have to refer to these diagrams in the text and would rather have them as equations (i.e. with and equation number) rather than a figure. I have tried just putting it in an equation environment but it neither centers the diagram (as ma)

Comment: Please explain more why putting them as figures is no good. Presumably because you want to refer to commutative diagrams as if they were equations? Buy why can't you just refer to figures instead?

Comment: @Seamus: In a math paper, commutative diagrams are functionally like equations, so the coherent thing is to label both in the same way. In a math paper, in which one customarily refers to dozens, if not hundreds, of equations, writing "Figure 32" instead of (32) is cumbersome. Also the label "Figure 32" takes up more (vertical) space than does a margin equation number. Surely there are still other reasons, but those are what occur to me.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current  bounding  box.center)]
......
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
```

Copied from Mtikz.pdf.

Comment: That's really slick---the `[baseline=(current  bounding  box.center)]` centers the equation reference number, rather than having it at the bottom of the picture.

Comment: Exactly. "equation" puts the reference number on the baseline of the picture, so the solution is to move the baseline.

Comment: And it works for all sorts of other things, too, like labelling for lists! that's great---thanks!

Comment: Could the example about be edited to include \hbox, then the answer would be complete?

Comment: I don't understand your comment --- there is no need for \hbox. Did you even try it?

Comment: My bad, I am very confused though, I was sure I tried putting it into an equation environment with no results, hence why i asked the question. In any case, thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there an easy way to have the number at the top, rather than the centre?

Comment: @Mephisto What if the TikZ picture lives in an external `standalone` file? Is there some way to have the modified baseline carry over into the main document?

Answer (score 5):

just place the TikZ picture into a box, for example using \text{} (which is an AMS command).

In case you do not use AMS, you can also use \hbox (which is a plain TeX command) instead.

Example which compiles without extra packages:

```
\begin{equation}
\hbox{\tikz\draw[draw=black,fill=red] (0,0) circle (5pt);}
\label{eq:test}
\end{equation}

\noindent
In (\ref{eq:test}), we see a TikZ picture.\dotfill
```

Christian

Comment: This is still using a distinct counter from the one used in the equation environment, so this might not work how the OP wanted it to...

Comment: @Seamus: How is the counter distinct? @user1537: `\eqref` handles the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks , hbox works for generating an appropriate equation number, but I am using the tikzpicture environment, which seems to conflict with \text{} which for some reason it doesnt like and the equation number is not placed correctly (at the bottom of the diagram rather than the middle).

Comment: @user1536: Use `\vcenter` instead of `\hbox`.

Comment: @TH Sorry, I didn't notice that you'd wrapped the `hbox` in an equation environment, I thought hbox had its own counter, that was distinct. I see now what you mean...

Comment: @TH: are you referring to the equation number placement because I didnt see a difference with pdflatex (the equation number is at the lower righthand corner rather than aligned with the right-middle of the diagram). This is mostly a personal stylistic choice that I would prefer but isnt strictly necessary. Also for some reason \raisetag seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 2):

If your Tikz image lives inside a `standalone` file, [Mephisto's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4346/62340) will not work since baseline modifications do not carry over to the main document, unfortunately.

Another option that *will* work in such cases is to wrap the Tikz image in [`amsmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath?lang=en)'s `aligned` environment.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \includestandalone{<tikzimage>}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

If this is used frequently (as OP states) one should consider wrapping this construction inside a custom environment.

```
\newenvironment{alignedeqn}
    {\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}}
    {\end{aligned}\end{equation}\ignorespacesafterend}
```

Answer (score 1):

To put the equation number on top or bottom (which is the default) just use the following commands:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current  bounding  box.north)]
....
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
```

or

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current  bounding  box.south)]
....
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
```

which is the default.

Comment: what if I want the equation number to be in the middle?

Comment: Nevermind box.east, did the job haha ;) Thanks anyway!